# Edit Facebook event graph api

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, events, facebook-c#-sdk

I need help editing an event previously created using the graph api.

Instead of editing the event, it creates a new one, what am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
public void editevent(string accessToken, string name, string description, DateTime starttime, string latitude, string longitude, string idevent)
{
    FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
    Dictionary<string, object> editEventParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    editEventParameters.Add("name", name);
    editEventParameters.Add("start_time", starttime.ToUniversalTime().ToString());
    editEventParameters.Add("owner", "Owner of event");
    editEventParameters.Add("description", description);

    JsonObject venueParameters = new JsonObject();

    if (latitude != "" && longitude != "")
    {
        venueParameters.Add("latitude", latitude);
        venueParameters.Add("longitude", longitude);
        editEventParameters.Add("venue", venueParameters);
    }

    createEventParameters.Add("privacy", "OPEN");

    JsonObject resul = facebookClient.Post("/" + idevent + "/events", editEventParameters) as JsonObject;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your idevent value?

Judging by your code snippet you are posting a new event to the page. To edit an event your GraphURL should look something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1222223333/
```

Where 1222223333 is the Facebook Object ID of the Event. Also, be sure to HTTP POST to that URL.